# Remove class from iframe and prevent default action

Tags: jquery

Here's my senario...

My iframe has a bunch of clickable buttons with a class of `.action-item`

```
$(".action-item").bind("click", function() {
   // do something
});
```

On the parent page I am targeting my iframe and removing the `.action-item` class. I've confirmed using Chrome developer tools, that the items do have the removed class.

```
$("#bottom-iframe").contents().find(".action-item:visible").each(function() {
     $(this).unbind('click');                   
     $(this).removeClass("action-item"); 
});
```

But unfortunately, the clicks are still registered and work, even when I remove the class. Is there a solution or something I'm overlooking?

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the binding. You probably want to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the event handler like so:

```
$("#bottom-iframe").contents().find(".action-item:visible").each(function() {                       
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $(this).removeClass("action-item"); 
});
```

Comment: This works, but as of jQuery 1.7 `.on()` and `.off()` are preferred.

Comment: True, I rolled with unbind since he was using bind.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I tried using .off() as well and the clicks are still registered and performing the normal action.

Comment: @Jako Please update your original post with the code you are trying that doesn't work.